# how do i Create a class called "Authenticator" in php that accepts a file

Tags: php

how do i Create a class called "Authenticator", with a constructor “Authenticator($filename)” that takes the filename of a password file as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Class [constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon) in PHP are created like this:

```
class Authenticator {
    function __construct($filename) {
        // do stuff with the filename here
    }
}
```

Then used like:

```
$auth = new Authenticator('filenameGoesHere');
```